# Is there a way to keep repeating the arraylist. like arraylist has 12, but it will continue to count while using the same list

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have figure this Zodiac sign with using %12 but I want to create this without that but I cant figure it out
is there a way to keep it counting while repeating the same list?

Heres the code. thanks

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String ans=null;        
    System.out.print("Enter your Birth Year: ");
    int birthYear= scan.nextInt();
    do{
        String[] sign = {"Monkey", "Rooster", "Dog", "Pig", "Rat", "Ox", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Dragon", "Snake", "Horse", "Sheep"};
        for(int i=0; i<sign.length; i++){
            ans=sign[birthYear];
        }

    }while(ans==null);
    System.out.println("Your Zodiac Sign is: "+ans);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fist of all your problem doesn't need to iterate all the years to find sign. You can use modulus operator find equivalent year and after you can directly access sign from the array.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String ans = null;
    System.out.print("Enter your Birth Year: ");

    String[] sign = {"Monkey", "Rooster", "Dog", "Pig", "Rat", "Ox", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Dragon", "Snake", "Horse", "Sheep"};
    int birthYear = scan.nextInt();
    do {

        int mod = birthYear % 12;
        ans = sign[mod];

    } while (ans == null);
    System.out.println("Your Zodiac Sign is: " + ans);
```

Comment: what is the point of the `while` loop?  If if does loop, it will loop forever.

Comment: it will not loop forever because ans assigned non null value inside the block. I don't know what question owners logic may be he will take more than one year until something. I didn't want to make any change that he got confuse.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `List<String>` you can do a simple `get`

```
    List<String> signs = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Monkey", "Rooster", "Dog", 
                "Pig", "Rat", "Ox", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Dragon", "Snake", "Horse", "Sheep"});

    String result = signs.get(1994 % 12);
    System.out.println(result);
```

**output**

```
Dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy solution although not that efficient: note the use of NESTED loops

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

String ans=null;        
System.out.print("Enter your Birth Year: ");
int birthYear= scan.nextInt();
do{
    String[] sign = {"Monkey", "Rooster", "Dog", "Pig", "Rat", "Ox", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Dragon", "Snake", "Horse", "Sheep"};
  for(int j=0;j<=birthYear;j+=12)
    for(int i=0; i<sign.length; i++){
        if( (j*12 + i)==birthYear) ans=sign[i];
    }
   }

}while(ans==null);
System.out.println("Your Zodiac Sign is: "+ans);
```

Comment: what is the point of the while loop? If if does loop, it will loop forever.

Comment: you're right, that was in the op's solution.  it can be deleted. But it won't run forever, so it really doesn't cause a problem